# IF para verificar quantidade necessária para determinado KG

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso fazer um IF em Javascript. Vou explicar:

Um cliente vende:

- Barricas de 40kg.
- Bisnaga de 3kg.

Não estou sabendo fazer esse IF. A ideia é, mostrar no campo `qtd40kg` Somente multiplos de 40, que é o peso, ou seja:

Se eu preciso de 40k no campo mostra 1, 80kg mostra 2, 120kg mostra 3, isso porque são multiplos de 40.

Agora no campo `qtd3kg` é um pouco diferente, ele é múltiplos de 3kg que ira preencher o intervalo entre `qtd40kg`.

**Link** https://jsfiddle.net/2w84ec18/

Ex:

**qtd40kg**

```
40kg  -> qtd40kg = 1un;
80kg  -> qtd40kg = 2un;
120kg -> qtd40kg = 3un;
160kg -> qtd40kg = 4un;
.
.
.
Até 1.000kg
```

**qtd3kg**

```
0kg -> qtd3kg = 0un;
3kg -> qtd3kg = 1un;
3kg -> qtd3kg = 1un;
9kg -> qtd3kg = 2un;
.
.
.
Até 30kg, depois ele irá fazer assim:
```

**Vamos supor que:**

```
peso = 43;
Então ``qtd40kg = 1`` e ``qtd3kg = 1``.

peso = 46;
Então ``qtd40kg = 1`` e ``qtd3kg = 2``.

peso = 49;
Então ``qtd40kg = 1`` e ``qtd3kg = 3``.


peso = 126;
Então ``qtd40kg = 3`` e ``qtd3kg = 2``.
```

**Link** https://jsfiddle.net/2w84ec18/

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Esse é um nível muito alto para mim.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Olá @Bacco, edirei. Acho melhor em JS. Obrigado.

Comment: Melhorou. E se a pessoa poe 5kg, ou algum outro valor que não dá multiplo, tipo 25kg, o que é pra acontecer?

Comment: @Bacco Se for 5kg seria 2 bisnaga de 3kg. 25kg seria 9 bisnagas de 3kg. e no campo ``qtd40kg`` fica como ZERO, isso porque a quantidade não é igual a superior a 40kg. Somente apartir de 40Kg o ``qtd40kg`` começa a receber valor.

Comment: Você quer quer por exemplo: 0 a 39 = 0, 40 a 79 = 1, ... ? É assim?

Comment: @Bacco a função do ``qtd3kg`` é preencher o espaço que as barricas de 40kg deixa. De 40kg até 80kg, tem vários kg para ser preenchido. A bisnaga de 3kg é para preencher esse espaço, maximizando a quantidade de massa.

Comment: E se a pessoa quiser 42, é uma de 40 e uma de 3, com erro de 1 kg, ou são 14 de 3, dando certinho 42?

Comment: @Bacco vamos supor que você precise de 60kg de massa, mais do que isso iria jogar fora. Se só tivesse barrica de 40kg, então teria que comprar 80kg, e 20kg iria se perder. Com a ajuda das bisnagas de 3kg, é possivel chegar o mais perto possível da necessidade do cliente. Nesse exemplo de 60kg seria (1 de 40kg e 7 de 3kg), totalizando 61kg. Nesse caso a perda é de 1kg apenas.

Comment: @Bacco, as bisnagas são mais caras, por isso não pode direto. No seu caso acima seria assim: Comprado 42kg seria 1un de 40kg e 1un de 3kg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creio que assim fica bem simples, pode testar aqui mesmo funcionando:

```js
function calc() {
  var peso = document.getElementById( 'peso' ).value;
  var b40  = Math.floor( peso / 40 );
  var b3   = Math.ceil( ( peso - b40 * 40 ) / 3 );
  
  document.getElementById( 'qtd40kg' ).value = b40;
  document.getElementById( 'qtd3kg'  ).value = b3;
}
```

```html
Peso:<br>
<input type="number" id="peso">

<p>QTD Barricas de 40kg:<br>
  <input type="number" id="qtd40kg">

<p>QTD bisnagas de 3kg:<br>
  <input type="number" id="qtd3kg">

<p><input type="button" id="calcular" value="Calcular" onclick="calc();">
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção com Jquery:

```js
var barricas = $('#qtd40kg');
var bisnagas = $('#qtd3kg');

$('#peso').on('input', function(){
var pesoTotal = $(this).val();
var x = Math.floor(pesoTotal%40);
var y = x/3;
barricas.val(Math.floor(pesoTotal/40))
bisnagas.val(Math.floor(y))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Peso:<br>
  <input type="number" id="peso">
  
  <p>QTD Barricas de 40kg:<br>
  <input type="number" id="qtd40kg">
  
  <p>QTD bisnagas de 3kg:<br>
  <input type="number" id="qtd3kg">
  
  <p><input type="button" id="calcular" value="Calcular">
```